# (isset($_POST['submitted'])) doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, html

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I've been watching different videos on this problem, and been searching for answers for a long time.

When I hit the submit button on the web page, the fields get cleared and nothing else happens. There is probably a simple mistake, but I can't find out what I'm doing wrong

```
<a1>
    <h1>Registrer ny bruker</h1>
    <hr>
    <form method="post" action="" >
        <input type="text" name="surName" placeholder="Etternavn" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="givenName" placeholder="Fornavn" required>
        <br><br>
        <select name="gender">
            <option value="male">male</option>
            <option value="female">female</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Alder" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="e-post" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Brukernavn" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Passord" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Registrer">
    </form>

</a1>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    $mysqli = new mysqli('my database username and password');

    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
    $surName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['surName']);
    $givenName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['givenName']);
    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $gender = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
    $age = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['age']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO blog_user (first_name, last_name, age, gender, user_password, user_name, mail)
            VALUES ('$givenName','$surName','$age','$gender','$password','$username','$email')
            ";

    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($insert) {
        echo "Succes!";
    } else {
        die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Edit : I made a small typo when I first added this, so the first answers did not fix my problem. I did not give them a down vote, and I'm sorry I made a typo.

Comment: if that is the complete code you don't have anywhere where you connect to a database

Comment: you went and edited your question http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43421392/2 without marking it as an edit and stating in the comments area for it that you made a mistake from your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43421392/1

Comment: It's not the complete code, and It does connect to the database if I remove the if statement.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem, Fred. I tried to edit it before someone answered my question, but I was to slow.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    $mysqli = new mysqli('my database username and password');
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
    $surName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['surName']);
    $givenName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['givenName']);
    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $gender = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
    $age = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['age']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO blog_user (first_name, last_name, age, gender, user_password, user_name, mail)
            VALUES ('$givenName','$surName','$age','$gender','$password','$username','$email')
            ";

    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($insert) {
        echo "Succes!";
    } else {
        die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

you have missed if statement.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer his as it would still execute

Comment: I'm sorry, that was just a typo. It doesn't work with the if statement

Comment: Since the OP marked both of us down for correcting the obvious, I marked you up.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but this wouldn't actually solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Your code is "clearing the fields" because your form is always presented first with default values. *The default values are not given with the input fields, so it's therefore "cleared" everytime you execute your php-file*.

```
<form method="post" action="" >
<input type="text" name="surName" placeholder="Etternavn" required>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="givenName" placeholder="Fornavn" required>
<br><br>
<select name="gender">
<option value="male">male</option>
<option value="female">female</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Alder" required>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="e-post" required>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Brukernavn" required>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Passord" required>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Registrer">
</form>
```

**For this reason you should use the form-request-part before you show the form**

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    $mysqli = new mysqli('my database username and password');
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
    $surName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['surName']);
    $givenName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['givenName']);
    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $gender = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
    $age = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['age']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO blog_user (first_name, last_name, age, gender, user_password, user_name, mail)
            VALUES ('$givenName','$surName','$age','$gender','$password','$username','$email')
            ";

    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($insert) {
        echo "Succes!";
    } else {
        die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

and show default values something like this...

```
<form method="post" action="" >
<input type="text" name="surName" placeholder="Etternavn" 
required value="<?php echo $surName;?>">
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="givenName" placeholder="Fornavn" 
required value="<?php echo $givenName;?>">
```

**etc...**

> NOTE Database-query should be using prepared statements to avoid sql
>   injections.

Comment: I realize it takes more effort from Answerers, but consider "forcing the OP's hand" and only deliver answers that implement best practices (like prepared statements).  Only by flooding SO pages with proper querying methods, will we have any chance of impacting the the droves of insecure queries being used.  Merely telling under-performing coders that they are doing wrong is usually insufficient.  (I've done a silent oath to myself to always deliver prepared statements (or PDO) when appropriate in all future answers I post.)

Answer (score -4):

Try this instead...

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
```

Comment: You made a typo and then down voted me for correcting your typo first. That makes other people not want to help you very much.

Comment: Hi Difster. I did not downvote you, someone else did. Probably the same person that downvoted me.

Comment: This is an objectively poor answer.  It makes no attempt at explaining what was wrong with the code in the Question, or why this code would fix it.  As such, the downvote was fully deserved.  (You could ... of course ... improve the answer.)

Comment: I added the obvious "if" before the code. No explanation was really needed. Feel free to provide your own explanation.